# Trying to snap child objects's vertex groups to bones pose

Tags: animation, bones, vertex-groups, snapping

I got a model in a stiff pose full of properly named vertex groups and an armature with a pose and an animation that have the bones with the same names as the vertex groups, but all of the bones are in the starting position of the animation, and I cant seem to add the animation after making the armature the parent.

I have been trying to match each vertex group to its designated bone to no avail. I have tried all ctrl+p options and no post or search has helped me. Is there a way to snap all vertex groups to the position and angle of their named bones? Without having to do them manually one by one since there are alot of them.

[image: pic of frame and model]
And also, I am using version 2.83

An update: This is what happenns on armature deform
[image: armature deform]

Some parts dont move to their bone, some dont even move from their current position but all of them follow the movement of the animation. Im not even sure whats going on with some parts being way up high.

Blender file: https://pasteall.org/blend/31cbb473f7464423a4d9266d9b75ab26

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ please upload the file or show some screenshot of the mesh and the armature.

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: Blend file needed.

Comment: Added the blender file

Comment: There are too many issues in this file, I suggest to rebuild it from scratch, after a better understanding of 3D rigging and animation workflows, starting with something simpler.

Comment: Some of the issues: bad topology, triangles, intersecting geometry, wrong bone and vertex groups names, wrong proportions between rig and body. Requires more advanced work to repair than rebuild from scratch. I suggest you the Humane rigging free youtube course, from Nathan Vegdahl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J-XN38EnhQ&list=PLE211C8C41F1AFBAB&index=1

Comment: I see, thank you very much!